# Area 51 Google+ link for promoting commitments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, commitment-phase

I'm looking at promoting [The Workplace](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30887/the-workplace) commitment and I notice that there's no Google+.  Is this something that could be added?

[image]

Comment: Hmm, good call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Delicious share link has been replaced with a Google+ share link.