# Google+ link not showing up in Area 51 Share This dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

Recently [the Delicious link was replaced with the Google+ link on Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123353/area-51-google-link-for-promoting-commitments).  However, the dialog box isn't appearing correctly if you are clicking the 'Share This' link located below the # of commitments.

[image: Area51 drop-down share this not showing G+ link]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woops, missed it here. Delcious has been replaced by Google+ in the Share This dialog now as well. Thanks.